# Form generated from form cache displays, but missing name and value attributes

Tags: forms, caching, theming

I'm having a problem displaying a cached multi-step form in a custom module which generates custom entities.

1. After two steps, the form posts to an external URL (action changed with hook_form_form_id_alter).
2. If the external URL returns errors, the form is pulled from cache with form_get_cache() and displayed using drupal_render().
3. Form displays okay, but field elements are missing name and value attributes.
4. Printing the form object retrieved from cache shows expected values (#entity, fields, and user input associated with fields).

   ```
     $form_state = array(
       'submitted' => FALSE,
       'rebuild' => FALSE,
       'cache' => TRUE,
     );

     $form = form_get_cache($form_build_id, $form_state);

     $output = drupal_render($form);
   ```

I suspect that I need to rebuild $form_state input/values or am missing a form rebuild step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Use form_get_cache() to get the cached entity, throw that into $form_state, and then use drupal_build_form() to put it together again.

```
    $form_state = array(
        'submitted' => FALSE,
        'rebuild' => FALSE,
        'cache' => TRUE,
    );

    // Pull the entity object from cache.
    $cached_form = form_get_cache($form_build_id, $form_state);
    $myentity = $cached_form['#entity'];

    $form_state['myentity'] = $myentity;
    $output = drupal_build_form('myentity_form', $form_state);
```